# Use MS Access Database with Unity3D

Tags: c#, ms-access, unity-game-engine

How can I use MS Access database within a Unity3D game ?

MS Access Database availability with .NET is easy, with ADO.NET, but I'm not familiar with the process to use `System.Data`, and `System.Data.OleDb` in Unity3D 5, and how to add references to my project.

Moreover, I tried to compile my own dll from Visual Studio, using Data dans Data.OleDb, but when I import it in my Asset Folder, it come with an exception :

`System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The Classes in the module cannot be loaded.`

I guess it's because of my references problems.
Does anyone can help me to add the right references to my Unity project ?

Comment: Instead of using MS Access, just get SQL Server Express. The free edition is virtually full-featured for everything you'll need to use it for. Most likely, the issue you're having is because the version of the C# compiler that Unity uses isn't built to handle those DLLs.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to make a program that allow to access a lot of data (from Revit) inside a Unity3D simulation. And this Data can easily be exported to the Access format, and I'm not sure that it we can export it to SQL. Moreover, it was also interesting to use all data within a single file, for portability purposes. But I'll give it a try !

Comment: SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine.

Comment: If SQLite is an option - there is a free asset on the Asset store that handles it from Unity: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/20660 - Never used it before, so I can't vouch on it's worth

Comment: Did you set: unity - edit - project settings - player - other settings - optimization - api compatibility level - .net 2.0 ?

Comment: @Dean did you find the solution? can u update the answer please i am looking for same.

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan : I never made it ; I made a workaround by exporting the access database to a local MySQL server I could reach with my app

Comment: Why do you even caps lock your comment ?
My use case was a proof of concept for a non-distribution product. I just needed to make the thinks work, whatever the way. I was not making something intended to be perfect in any way.